# react passive event handler for a scroll

Tags: javascript, reactjs, events, event-handling, dom-events

I have a event handler for a scroll in my react and I am trying to make it passive. But it isn't working, I keep getting this warning in my console:

> Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more
> responive.

So here is where I read the event:

```
bindEventListeners()
{
    EventContainer.readWindowEvent('scroll', this.onScroll);
}
```

Here is my `readWindowEvent` function in my EventContainer.js file:

```
static readWindowEvent(slug, callback, passive = true)
    {
        let result = null;

        let allowed = this.getAllowedWindowEventListeners().indexOf(slug) != -1;

        if (!allowed) {
            result = console.error(
                'You cannot register ' + slug + ' on the window. Allowed events: ' +
                this.getAllowedWindowEventListeners().join(', ')
            )
        }

        if (allowed) {
            result = window.addEventListener(
                slug,
                callback,
                {passive: passive}
            );
        }

        return result;
    }
```

On this line:

> {passive: passive}

I get the following error in my editor:

> Argument type {passive: boolean} is not assignable to parameter type boolean

Anyone knows what I am doing wrong here?

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Change the function parameters to `(slug, callback, passive)` and change the 3rd parameter in `addEventListener()` to `{ passive: passive === true }`

Comment: @Archer This gives the same error in my editor, unfortunately. I compiled my react and did a getEventListeners in my console and it still says passive: false :'(

Comment: Sorry that didn't help.  I don't see anything wrong with the code, and if you just mimic it with a simple 1-liner in the browser console it works fine.  It may be something React-specific, in which case I can't help.  Hope someone comes along that can!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a little late to answer now, but I had the same issue. A workaround is using the `any`-type on the object which is passed in:

```
let passiveObject: any = { passive: true }
obj.addEventListener(evt, func, passiveObject)
```

Hope this helps someone in the future!

Answer (score -2):

there is no any reason to have scroll listener passive!
Please read docs carefully - any touch wheel & click listeners in the scrolled div must be passive - it's main goal of passive listeners

Comment: What if the div isn't scrolled, but zoomed by the scroll wheel? Like a map? You certainly do want to preventDefault on the scroll event, in that case.